# Does tanz assumes all complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z)=tanz$,$z$ $\in$ $C$

a)assumes all complex numbers

b)assumes none of complex numbers

c)assumes all complex numbers except $i$

d)assumes all complex numbers except $i$ and $-i$

I think answer is c, please help me!
I find that $tanz=-i$$\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}$. What is the next step?

Comment: That would be very peculiar indeed, given that $\tan\bar z=\overline{\tan z}$.

Comment: ... or $\tan(-z) = -\tan(z)$.

Comment: $\tan z=-i\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}$. So $\tan z=\pm i$ is equivalent to $e^{iz}=0$ or $e^{-iz}=0$ and it is well-known that the exponential does not assume the value 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(b) is obviously false, given that e.g. $\tan(i)$ is not purely real.

As pointed out in comments, if there is no number $z$ such that $\tan(z)=i$, there is also no number $z$ such that $\tan(z)=-i$. So (c) cannot be true.

This leaves (a) or (d), and if you already know that (a) is false, that leaves only (d).

Comment: can you give discription for $ tan(z)=i$.